# optimum hardware setup for android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

is there a "best" setup for the android emulator? It runs terribly slow on my mac os as well as my windows 7 32-bit. I was just wondering if there's an optimal setup as far as 32-bit vs 64 bit, or linux/windows/mac is concerned?

Comment: Are you running an ARM or x86 system image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the bad news is that everyone has the same problem . its dead slow !! . try using the Intel based emulator(instead of the arm-7 )and download the haxm software that Intel provides. Its available for the Mac too. 
You can download the Intel based emulator and the haxm software (only for windows I guess) from the SDK manager.

Comment: I have to agree, even on a pretty high end development machine the emulator is pretty damn slow. It's faster the higher spec the PC but in general there's a lot of waiting around wondering what's gone wrong.